# Python Google Play Store App

Tags: android, python, search

I want to search the google play store with python.

My idea:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'chrome')]

term = "faceboook"
query = "http://play.google.com/store/search?q="+term

htmltext = br.open(query).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
search = soup.findAll("div", class_="card-content id-track-click id-track-impression")

print search
```

Well, then I get at least the package name:

```
[<div class="card-content id-track-click id-track-impression" data-docid="com.facebook.katana"
```

Now my question and problem:
How do I get ONLY the package name? 
Or do anyone know an API which do this for me?

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Package name you mean data-docid? can you give an example?